# Sending multiple photos from server to client stuck in a while loop

Tags: java, sockets, server, client

I'm building a server/client application that consists of sending and saving information about photos.

I've managed to successfully send 1 photo from the client to the server at a time. Now, I'm trying to get the server to send the client multiple photos.

I used the same code I used before and put it in a for loop. However, when I run the code, the client side gets stuck on the `while` loop. What's especially weird is that, if I ask the server to send 3 photos, the client successfully receives the 3 and completes the first 2 loops, both the while and the for, correctly (I observed this with some prints on the console). However, it does not leave the `while` loop on the last iteration. I also noticed that, if I close the server, the client is able to finish the loop.

I would like to know why the client is getting stuck on the last iteration of the while loop, even though it seems like it's correctly receiving the entirety of the images (I can open them).

The code I used on the server side is the following:

```java
for (int i=0; i<n;i++) {
    try {
        //photo
        File f = new File("photo.jpg");
        
        BufferedInputStream reader = new BufferedInputStream( new FileInputStream( f ) );
                    
        //sending the photo
        byte[] buffer = new byte[ 4096 ];
        int bytesRead;
        while ( (bytesRead = reader.read(buffer)) != -1 ) {
            //ObjectOutputStream outStream is being passed to the function as an argument
            outStream.write( buffer, 0, bytesRead );
            }
        reader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

It's somewhat simplified, because in reality I'm iterating through a list of photos and updating `f` on each cycle.

The code on the client side looks like this:

```java
for (int j=0; j<n; j++) {
    try {
        File result = new File("fromServer.jpg");
        BufferedOutputStream out2 = new BufferedOutputStream( new FileOutputStream( result ) );
                
        byte[] buffer = new byte[ 4096 ];
        int bytesRead;
        //ObjectInputStream in was created earlier in the code, inside the same function
        while ( (bytesRead = in.read( buffer )) != -1 ) {
            out2.write( buffer, 0, bytesRead );
        }
        out2.flush();
        out2.close();
        } catch (IOException e3) {
            e3.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Once again, I simplified the code because the file name and location is also updated on each iteration but this is the core of the idea.

I would like to know why the client doesn't leave the while loop on the last image. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It looks strange that your client reads `in` until end-of-file and then loops around and keeps reading from `in`.  Is there additional logic that "resets" `in` that we're not seeing here.  Or in other words, how does the client know when the first image ends and the second one starts?

Comment: @Erik You're right, the client wasn't receiving any information about where the image ends. I've updated it so that the client receives the image size! However, now I'm getting exceptions thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach shown will not work for multiple files.  You need to indicate where one file ends and the next begins.  For instance, first send the number of files (so the receiver knows how many times it needs to loop), and then for each file, send the file's size before sending the file's bytes (so the receiver knows when to stop reading a file and prepare for the next file).

Try something more like this:

```java
try {
    outStream.writeInt(n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        File f = new File("photo.jpg");

        long fileSize = f.length();
        outStream.writeLong(fileSize);

        BufferedInputStream reader = new BufferedInputStream( new FileInputStream( f ) );
        byte[] buffer = new byte[ 4096 ];
        int bytesRead;
        long curr = 0;

        while (curr < fileSize) {
            bytesRead = reader.read(buffer, 0, (int) Math.min(fileSize - curr, (long) 4096));
            if (bytesRead == -1) {
                // premature EOF, receiver is expecting more bytes
                // than are actually available (should not happen, unless
                // someone else is manipulating the file while we have it
                // open), so just fail here ...
                throw something;
            }
            outStream.write( buffer, 0, bytesRead );
            curr += bytesRead;
        }

        reader.close();
    }
}
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

```java
try {
    int n = in.ReadInt(n);

    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        long fileSize = in.readLong();

        File result = new File("fromServer" + Integer.toString(j) + ".jpg");
        BufferedOutputStream out2 = new BufferedOutputStream( new FileOutputStream( result ) );                
        byte[] buffer = new byte[ 4096 ];
        int bytesRead;
        long curr = 0;

        while (curr < fileSize) {
            bytesRead = in.read(buffer, 0, (int) Math.min(fileSize - curr, (long) 4096));
            if (bytesRead == -1) {
                // sender disconnected prematurely, just fail here ...
                throw something;
            }
            out2.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            curr += bytesRead;
        }
        out2.flush();
        out2.close();
    }
}
catch (IOException e3) {
    e3.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for the answer! I tried to do it like that and added, on the client side, inside if (bytesRead == -1), this code: `throw new EOFException("error");` (even though I wasn't sure about what exception to throw). Now, the client exits the loop successfully but the exception is being thrown in that place. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Wait nevermind! I just fixed it! Turns out I was sending the number of photos to the client in the wrong place. Thank you so much for your help!